# How to replace the date format to 'SYSDATE' of a unix file

Tags: sed

I have a file with few lines . File_Name : `test.sql`

```
INSERT INTO ADJUSTMENT_REASON VALUES (17-MAY-18,,'','','','S','C','Y','N',,'Y','N','N','A','BAN','Y','B','Mobile Internet Discount','N','','','N','B','','','N','N','');

INSERT INTO ACTIVITY_REASON_TEXT VALUES ('ADJ','','','',17-MAY-18,'','','','Mobile Internet Discount','Mobile Internet Discount','Y','N','','A',,'',,'','','');
```

I want to replace the date `17-MAY-18` to SYSDATE from each line of the file.

Comment: I want to add one more thing here.
Actually , I am preparing one script and it will run on daily basis.
This script will create one sql file in which , there will be more then 100 sql queries. Above one is the example.
So every day , this date will change.

Comment: I want to add one more thing here.
Actually , I am preparing one script and it will run on daily basis.
This script will create one sql file at the end in which , there will be more than 100 sql queries. Above one is the example.
So every day , this date will change.
I want a generic unix command which will replace current date to SYSDATE.

Date format : DD-MON-YY

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/17-MAY-18/SYSDATE/g' <test.sql >new-test.sql
```

This would create `new-test.sql` with the contents

```
INSERT INTO ADJUSTMENT_REASON VALUES (SYSDATE,,'','','','S','C','Y','N',,'Y','N','N','A','BAN','Y','B','Mobile Internet Discount','N','','','N','B','','','N','N','');

INSERT INTO ACTIVITY_REASON_TEXT VALUES ('ADJ','','','',SYSDATE,'','','','Mobile Internet Discount','Mobile Internet Discount','Y','N','','A',,'',,'','','');
```

Comment: I want to add one more thing here.
Actually , I am preparing one script and it will run on daily basis.
This script will create one sql file at the end in which , there will be more than 100 sql queries. Above one is the example.
So every day , this date will change.
I want a generic unix command which will replace current date to SYSDATE.

Date format : DD-MON-YY

Comment: @KUNALTHAKUR Why is the SQL not generated with `SYSDATE` inserted in the first place?

Comment: I am using pl/sql 

vtemp_statement :='INSERT INTO ADJUSTMENT_REASON VALUES ('''||trim(vrec.reason_code)||''',''||TRUNc(SYSDATE)||'','||NULL||','''||
vrec.OPERATOR_ID||''','''||vrec.APPLICATION_ID||''','''||vrec.DL_SERVICE_CODE||''','''||vrec.DL_UPDATE_STAMP||''',''');

I have declared one variable and stored the whole sql_query in that variable. 
using this variable , I inserted the whole query in temp_table and spooled the temp_table data in a test.txt file.